# Graphing polar curves: Conchoid of Nicomedes

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I aim to solve the following problem:

[image]

I managed to prove that $\sec\theta>0$ ,however, I have had little success in graphing it and showing it is a conchoid of Nicomedes. The locus of points (source MEI) is given by

[image]

I do not understand why the graph is symmetric around $b$ as I think that $r=\pm b + a\sec\theta$ meaning that the graph should be the same but shifted by b, but this is wrong according to MEI and the markscheme. If anybody could shine some light into how to graph the polar curve in $(i)$ I would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit** Here is the mark scheme for the first part of the question [image]

Comment: The wikipedia article on conchoids has some useful information.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the response. The wikipedia page does not seem to have a lot of detail as of how to graph it. Moreover, this question is from the Cambridge Undergraduate Admissions exam so I doubt that we are supposed to know what a conchoid is.

Comment: The question tells you as much as you need to know about what a conchoid is. The article tells you what (x,y) is expressed parametrically, and what the line L, the fixed point, and the distance d are. Try using $x=rcos\theta$ etc if you need to derive the equations for $x,y$ yourself.

Comment: @Peter This is what I did, however, we are not suppose to do that according to the mark scheme. This is why I posted this asking how would one graph it and know that it is symmetric around b by just looking at the equation and only having $\sec\theta>0$

Comment: Re the symmetry, the question does not suggest it, so forget it. It is not even symmetric about the line x=a, though your graph is not accurate enough to show that. Does the marking scheme suggest that marks are deducted for putting x and y in parametric form? There may be no marks for it because it is just a means to an end. I would be doing it because I find it easier to think in rectangular coordinates than polar coordinates.

Comment: @Peter I have added the markscheme for the first part of the question. The graphing part is 3 marks thus it should not take a while to do. As I said in the question I struggle with graphing it just by looking at the equation as I intuitively thought that $r=a\sec\theta +b$ would be the same as $r=a\sec\theta -b$ but shifted, which it is obviously not. Any ideas on how to get an idea for the general shape from the equation and deduce that $d=b$?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: You just need to prove that the polar eqn $|r-a\sec\theta|=b$ encodes the description "locus of pts that are a fixed distance [$d$ from a line $L$] measured along lines through [a pt $A$]". To do this, you need only identify the pt, distance, and line involved. Unsurprisingly, the origin plays the role of pt $A$; the absolute value suggests that $b$ plays the role of distance $d$. What's left is to show that $|r-a\sec\theta|$ measures "dist from locus to $L$ along lines through $A$"; so, simply observe that $r=a\sec\theta$ is the polar eqn of a line (namely, the vertical $x=a$).

Comment: @MathsWizzard I know I wouldn't be able to do a reasonable sketch unless I already knew the answer or else expressed the equations in Cartesian form.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the answer. Could you go into more detail as how to graph the polar curve given the equation and how you deduced that $b=d$ ?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: As for why $b=d$: interpret $|r-a\sec\theta|$ as "distance from locus to line"; the eqn gives that dist as $b$, and the locus calls that dist to be $d$. It's a bit like looking at the first couple of lines of the mark scheme in reverse. The distance from the origin to the line $x=a$, along lines through the origin, is $r=a\sec\theta$; the locus is $b$ units *farther* or *closer* than the line, so we have $r=a\sec\theta\pm b$, which we can write as $|r-a\sec\theta|=b$.

Comment: @MathsWizzard: Your graph isn't terrible; it could just use a few more sample points. These would reveal that the locus has a bit of a bulge on the origin side, while being somewhat flatter on the other side. ... The mark scheme's graph isn't so great. The distances from the line to the locus for the sample points on the inclined line don't look equal to $b$. They don't even look equal to each other! So, the person who drew that sketch shouldn't judge others too harshly. :)

Comment: @Blue thank you for the answer. Regarding $|r-a-\sec\theta|$ how did you deduce it is the distance from the locus to the line $x=a$? Because when I tried to proveit I get $|x-a|=b\cos\theta$ (I multiplied both sides by $\cos\theta$). In my equation the left hand sides yields the distance from $x$ to $a$ rather than distance from locus to a line. If you could explain that I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @MathsWizzard: $|x-a|=b\cos\theta$ is correct. The $|x-a|$ part gives the horizontal offset of a point of the locus from the vertical line $x=a$, and so does $b\cos\theta$: the points on the locus are offset from points on the line by $b$ units in direction $\theta$ to the horizontal; $b\cos\theta$ gives the horizontal component of that offset ($b\sin\theta$ would be the vertical component). So, you've properly captured the nature of the locus. Substituting $x\to r\cos\theta$ gives the corresponding polar equation for that locus.